# Underscore generated for field called 'return' from swagger json

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have the following problem:

A DTO in swagger is defined as

```
"ExampleDto": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "exampleProperty": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "return": {
      "type": "number",
      "format": "double"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the generator makes '_return' in the resulting Java class.
Used generator: io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator

Can anybody help me with that, how I could generate it.

Comment: Maybe because `return` is a reserved word?

Comment: Synonyms for `return`: `yield`, `result`.

Comment: Do not use java reserve word (i.e return)

Comment: I understood that, but we got this API from another company and should use it. So is there no solution / workaround, so that the json is generated correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use java reserved keywords:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html